# *nix whose package manager DOES NOT split Python into multiple packages

Tags: package-management, python

Is there a *nix whose package manager *doesn't* split Python into multiple packages (typically something like `python` and `python-devel`). I'd really like to just get the entire standard library when I install it, since that's how it's designed to work. Thanks.

UPDATE: Some people are wondering what I mean, so here's an example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/123755. I realize it's not caused (in this instance) by a `python`/`python-devel` split, but it's the sort of issue I don't want to worry about. I just want to install the entirety of Python—with no weird tweaks of the `ImportError` handler, or std lib modules ripped out (for any reason)—and then let my package manager handle security updates, etc.

Comment: Once you install `python` you should have "the entire standard library" already. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I agree with phunehehe -- I'm not sure this question makes sense...

Comment: @simon: It isn't that. I think OP just doesn't know. She sees `-devel` and thinks, *oh, that means it has Python stdlib*.

Comment: devel is just header files. you don't need this unless you are going to compile/link against a python library.

Comment: @phunehehe @tshepang @simon @faheem it's really annoying to try to do any kind of real dev work on a system with split packages imo. This question makes sense, esp if you start thinking outside of python, and start. the -devel packages can be a real problem if you're using an external repo, or a backport, or something else, because then -devel doesn't always line up with the binary that's installed. I know I've had it. I don't use debian or suse, or any system that works like this for this very reason. So I think it's a good question.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I expect that a backported package will also have an accompanying -dev package. Unless I don't understand your point.

Comment: @xenoterracide: It would really be strange that you use Arch just because it doesn't split away -dev from core functionality!

Comment: @xenoterracide: the dev package is built from the same source package as the binary. they are available as a group. apt/aptitude should also pull them in together. file a bug if you think any of the above is not true.

Comment: Ah, after your update I see the problem.  I didn't notice a problem with `pstats` because it is not listed as a core module on http://docs.python.org/library/, but I see how that would be annoying.

Comment: @tshepang actually it's 1 of my 3 big reasons, binary, rolling, and no split -dev. On suse, some of the non default repo's, which are needed for multimedia, or newer binaries, there aren't accompanying -dev packages, or the deps don't all resolve right for them, because of things like X11 differences.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Such a situation just spells out *brokenness*. BTW u got a blog post talking about Arch love?

Comment: @Mikel: As explained on the linked bug report, the reason pstats isn't bundled with Debian (or Ubuntu) stdlib package is due to it's non-libre licence. I guess that's also one reason why it's not advertised as a 1st-class standard Python module.

Comment: @tshepang no...

Comment: @xenoterracide: huh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/) doesn't have separate packages for `-dev` and it's binary (unlike gentoo). There might be a few things, like `tk` which isn't pulled in by default. Here's the [`python package`](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/python/) for arch.

Comment: Oh, I see Arch Linux has a relaxed view regarding non-libre software.

Comment: which is fine with me... I want it to work

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/).  Since it installs everything from source, there are no `-dev` packages.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian (and therefore probably Ubuntu), running `apt-get install python` installs `python-minimal` and `python`, which results in all core modules being installed, which I assume is what you mean by "the entire standard library".

The only caveat I can find is that the Tk GUI stuff is all installed, but you need to install the `python-tk` package to use it properly.

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 41, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

So run `apt-get install python python-tk`, and you have everything you need.

Does that meet your criteria?